# MATLAB autohandle array out of bounds with give 0

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'd like to auto handle array out of bounds index access by giving 0 instead.

But what I have now is code like

```
evenIndexNext = 2*j+1 + 2*i ;
oddIndexPrev = 2*j+1 - i ;
evenValueNext = 0 ;
oddValuePrev = 0 ;
if( evenIndexNext <= n )
  evenValueNext = s( evenIndexNext ) ;
end
if( oddIndexPrev >= 1 ) 
  oddValuePrev = s( oddIndexPrev ) ;
end
```

Where `s` is the array.  A bit clunky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, you could do:

```
try
  evenValueNext = s( evenIndexNext ) ;
catch
  evenValueNext=0;
end
```

or, you could define a function to do that:

```
function y=checkBound(l,i)
  if (i<1) || (i>numel(l))
    y=0;
  else
    y=l(i);
  end
end

evenValueNext = checkBound(s,evenIndexNext);
oddValuePrev = checkBound(s,oddIndexPrev) ;
```

Comment: I guess a function's the best we can do

Answer (score 0):

You could define a new class to handle this. If you overloaded the subsref method of the class, you could tell it to check if the index was out of bounds, and return 0 if that was the case.